# x raised to the power 0 does not evaluate to 1

Tags: c#, math, unit-conversion

I created a class for doing unit conversions, specifically bytes to kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, etc. I have an `enum` with `B` through `PB`, but for some reason `1024^0` does not return `1` and it's not correctly converting from bytes to bytes or bytes to kilobytes, etc.

Here's my class:

```
public static class UnitConversion
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 1024^n
    /// </summary>
    public enum ByteConversionConstant
    {
        B = 0,
        KB = 1,
        MB = 2,
        GB = 3,
        TB = 4,
        PB = 5
    }

    public static string GetValueFromBytes(long bytes,
                            ByteConversionConstant constant)
    {
        int n = (int)constant;
        long divisor = 1024^n;
        return (bytes / divisor).ToString() + 
               Enum.GetName(typeof(ByteConversionConstant), constant);
    }
}
```

The following statement should return exactly the same value as `fileInfo.Length`, but since `1024^0` isn't returning `1`, it's showing the number of kilobytes. Note, I had the `GetValueFromBytes` method all in one line, but I separated it out to see what could be causing the miscalculation.

```
UnitConversion.GetValueFromBytes(fileInfo.Length, 
                                 UnitConversion.ByteConversionConstant.B)
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue with casting the `enum` to an `int` or if something gets lost when raising an `int` to an `int` and assigning it to a `long`, but this is strange behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using [the `^` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx), which is *not* an exponentiation operator. It's exclusive-OR.

Use [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) for exponentiation - or better, just use bit-shifting in this case:

```
long divided = bytes >> (n * 10);
return divided.ToString() + ...;
```

Alternatively, you could change your enum values to the actual values to divide by:

```
public enum ByteConversionConstant : long
{
    B = 1L << 0,
    KB = 1L << 10,
    MB = 1L << 20,
    GB = 1L << 30,
    TB = 1L << 40,
    PB = 1L << 50
}
```

Then:

```
long divided = n / (long) constant;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm not sure how I confused `Math.Pow` and the bitwise operater `^`.

Answer (score 7):

`^` is the [XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) operator. What you want to achieve is done via [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx).

Comment: @Pierre: Haha, indeed.

Comment: Thanks. But Jon's answer *is* better, so it is perfectly OK, that it has been upvoted more.

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure how I made such a rooky mistake with confusing the `^` XOR operator and `Math.Pow`.

Answer (score 6):

`^` is a bitwise operator, you are currently doing '1024 XOR 0'.

I think you are looking for `Math.Pow(1024, n);`, which is '1024 raised to the power 0'

Answer (score 3):

The `^` operator does not raise the number to that power, it is the [Bitwise XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) operator.

You want [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx)

```
long divisor = Math.Pow(1024, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Math.Pow().

^ is not used for powers, but for bitwise operations instead (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx for details).

Comment: And how's that different from rest of the answers?